# Mocking repository and callback issue

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have a Repository which I have mocked using Moq.

I have a Service which I have mocked. The service expects a repository in its constructor and I have successfully been able to do this.

The problem I am now facing is that, I want the Repository to not connect to the DB but instead use an in memory storage to query/perform operations against.

if I do this:

```
userMockRepository.Setup(r => r.Login(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
                  .Returns((User u) => users.Find(p => p.Password == u.Password &&
                                                       p.Username == u.Username));
```

then run the test, I get an exception:

> Parameter count mismatch

when the Service method is being called when about to invoke the Login on the UserRepository.

What am I doing wrong? Am I misunderstanding?

Essentially any Repository calls should be redirected or query against an in memory collection (i.e List)

this is my actual service layer method:

```
var user = uoWContext.UserRepository.Login(request.Username, request.Password);

if (user == null)
{
    response.Success = false;
    response.FailureInformation = "Invalid username or password";
}

return response;
```

When it gets to the line `uowContext.UserRepository.Login(...)` - this is where I get the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
userMockRepository.Setup(r => r.Login(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
                  .Returns((string pw, string un) => users.Find(u => u.Password == pw && u.Username == un));

                  // or

                  .Returns<string, string>((pw, un) => users.Find(u => u.Password == pw && u.Username == un));
```

The arguments of `Setup()` should correspond to the arguments of `Return()`.

Comment: One more - when I have a backing store of a List<T>, and I setup a method to do a callback, adding the item into the collection - the next time I add an item, I see that there were no items added previously to the collection. How would I make it so that the collection is persisted in the unit tests? I have a Repository and an IQueyable<T> if that helps. (Context being: AddItem)

Comment: @Ahmed: try to declare a list you add the items to not inside a lambda expression but in the outer scope, i.e. as a variable inside a test method.